# How to get existing s3 bucket(subdirectory)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

For a CDK app I'm working on, trying to get an existing s3 bucket path and then copy few local files to that bucket. However, I get this error when the code tries to search for the bucket,
`Failed to create resource. Command '['python3', '/var/task/aws', 's3', 'sync', '--delete', '/tmp/tmpew0gwu1w/contents', 's3://dir/subdir/']' returned non-zero exit status 1.` using the code below,

If anyone could help me with this, that'd be great, not sure if the 'bucket-name' parameter can take bucket path or not.

Line of code is as follows,
`IBucket byName = Bucket.fromBucketName(this, "bucket-name", "dir/subdir");`

Note: If I try to copy the files to the main directory(dir in this case), it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “path” is not part of the bucket name, it’s part of the object’s key (filename). Amazon S3 is an object store and doesn’t have directories like file systems do.

Technically, every object in a bucket is on the top level with the “path” being prefixed to its name.

So if you have something like `s3://bucket/path/sub-path/file.txt`, the **bucket** name is `bucket` and the **object key** (similar to a filename) is `path/sub-path/file.txt` with `path/sub-path/` being the **prefix**.

When using the `aws s3 sync` CLI command, the prefix gets converted into a directory structure on the local drive, and vice versa.

For more details, please refer to [How do I use folders in an S3 bucket?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html)

Comment: Great, happy to help!